# When kayword is mentioned forward latest message to other MT channel

Tags: automation, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I have a problem when create an automation to forward message between m. teams channel with Power Automates if a keyword is mentioned.

I have two different channels: channel 1 and channel 2.
I try to create an automation to do that:

On group 1 arrive an automatic message as type email.
When the human write "help" on chat group 1 channel i need forward latest message recive on channel to channel group 2.

I start to create a flow ad "When keywords are mentioned" and as keywords to search as "help".

First i start to create "Get Message" then "Post message in a chat or channel". The flow work successful but deprecate the message more time.

[flow succesful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnTcz.png)

On "Get Messages" on Team i put "Team ID" (cannot insert specific team ID) and on Channel i put "Channel ID" (cannot insert specific channel ID).

[setting flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Og3nu.png)

Comment: Could you please let us know in which step you are getting error and what error message you are getting? From the details provided it's not quite clear